# jquery change onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick

Hello I'm trying to create a on-line photalbum. So the idea is to have a picture and two  elements with a onclick event to load next and previous image in the album.
I created a function for this, but it only works once. If you press the previous or next button the onclick is executed, but the onclick properties are not changed and a simple alert box tells me that the code isn't executed the second time.

I am sorry for the dutch language in my code foto should be Photo!

My HTML looks like this.

```
<div id="fotolarge">
   <span class="arrow arrowright"></span>
   <span class="arrow arrowleft"></span>

   <span id="fotoloading"></span>
   <img id="foto"/>
</div>
```

My javascript looks like this

```
function loadPhoto(src){
   $("#fotoloading").css("z-index","3");
   $currentIndex = jQuery.inArray(src, $photoArray);

//next image
   $nextIndex = $currentIndex + 1;
   if($nextIndex < $photoArrayLength){
    $(".arrowright").attr("onclick", "loadPhoto('" + $photoArray[$nextIndex] + "')");
   }
   else{
    $(".arrowright").attr("onclick", "loadPhoto('" + $photoArray[0] + "')");
   }

//previous image
$previousIndex = $currentIndex - 1;
if($previousIndex >= 0){
    $(".arrowleft").attr("onclick", "loadPhoto('" + $photoArray[$previousIndex] + "')");
}
else{
    $(".arrowleft").attr("onclick", "loadPhoto('" + $photoArray[$photoArrayLength -1] + "')");
}

var loader = new ImageLoader(src);
loader.loadEvent = function(url, image){
    $("#fotoloading").css("z-index","2");
    $("#foto").replaceWith(image);
    $("#foto").css("display", "block");
    calcmiddle();
}
loader.load();
}
```

The variables $photoArray and $photoArrayLength are global variables.
$photArray holds a list of the sources of the images.
The Imageloader is not the problem, because is doesn't work either is that part is comment out.

I hope someone has an idea of how to fix this. I have tried the jquery .click() like this

```
$(".arrowright").click(function(){
  loadPhoto($photoArray[0]);
});
```

Then it works partly. It creates in infinite loop of executing loadPhoto();

Comment: For what it's worth, there are already excellent plugins to do this work for you. For slideshows: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ For a carousel: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

Comment: are you sure that $currentIndex is sets to something?

Comment: Can you give me full code with $photoArray, $photoArrayLength and ImageLoader so that I can make a fully working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better of using the click event to tell which direction you're going (1 or -1) and keep track of the current position, rather than re-writing the click event every time.

Comment: Thats a good idea, i will try that.
But do you know why the current code is nog working?